# Xcode's Main Thread Checker is complaining about something that is in the main thread

Tags: swift, xcode, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, dispatch-async

I have a subclass of UILabel called UILabelPadding:

```
class UILabelPadding: UILabel {

let padding = UIEdgeInsets(top: 4, left: 3, bottom: 4, right: 3)
override func drawText(in rect: CGRect) {
    super.drawText(in: UIEdgeInsetsInsetRect(rect, padding))
}

override var intrinsicContentSize : CGSize {
    let superContentSize = super.intrinsicContentSize
    let width = superContentSize.width + padding.left + padding.right
    let heigth = superContentSize.height + padding.top + padding.bottom
    return CGSize(width: width, height: heigth)
}

}
```

Sometimes when I'm running my app on my iPhone 6s, Main Thread Checker stops my program with the purple warnings pointing to my UILabelPadding variable that I declare in my main class.

```
var activityTextStatus = UILabelPadding()
```

I get the warnings:

1. -[UILabel initWithFrame:] must be used from main thread only
2. -[UIView init] must be used from main thread only

So everywhere I use activityTextStatus, I put it inside "DispatchQueue.main.async", but I still get the purple UI API called in background thread warnings. Is Main Thread Checker somehow wrong? I don't want to turn it off in case it's useful for letting me know any other problems, but I wish I could ignore it for just this problem, or resolve it if it's actually an issue.

Comment: Try declaring your variable as an implicitly unwrapped optional, as typically done for outlets.  var activityTextStatus : UILabelPadding!  Declare it but don't init it.  And obviously, init in some code that you guarantee to run on the main thread.

Comment: Thanks that seemed to have worked, and now does the same thing with other objects I declared similarly.